# I'm on Kubuntu and don't know how to add languages

Tags: command-line, keyboard, kubuntu, language-support

I'm on Kubuntu and tried to add a keyboard language through the GUI and nothing worked. I have been searching online for help and nothing answered my Question. Every time I try to install through the GUI It says missing packages. Thanks

BTW if I want to install other languages is there a package I can install to make it easier (BTW - By The way)

Comment: If it's a usual keyboard layout you want to add, no additional package is needed. So probably you were in the wrong section of the GUI. Please provide more details on which steps you took.

Comment: Can you specify which language in particular? I personally know many foreign languages are much more difficult to enable on Kubuntu than people seem to realize..